# When does javascript shallow copy vs. deep copy

Tags: javascript, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I have been looking through the stack overflow answers for a while now and have been unable to find a clear, non-contradicting answer to the following question.  When does Javascript shallow copy vs deep copy?  I have already looked at the popular answers in which case there are 400 answers/comments and everyone seems to be arguing about it.  If you know the answer for sure and are an expert, please help us all out.  If you have a link on the internet that explains this in total, which I was unable to find, that would be a great help as well.  Really appreciate it!

Comment: How are you copying? That makes a difference

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copying-stuff-in-javascript-how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies-b6d8c1ef09cd/

Comment: JavaScript *never* makes a copy at all, unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello, that's what I'm looking for!!

Comment: Hi @epascarello.  Do you want to make your answer with freecodecamp an official answer and get some points or should I make it an answer.  Just let me know no rush.  Can you also include that function parameters are pass-by-value.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copying-stuff-in-javascript-how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies-b6d8c1ef09cd/

Hi everyone.  Here is the answer to this question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Normally JavaScript doesn't make copies at all. Assigning variables, passing parameters, or returning values don't make copies, they just assign/pass references.

There are some built-in functions that can be used to make copies, such as [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). These only make shallow copies.

I don't think there are any standard JavaScript functions that make deep copies. However, there are functions in libraries like jQuery, lodash, and underscore.js that will do it. For instance, [`jQuery.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is similar to `Object.assign()`, but it has an optional `deep` parameter that indicates that it should perform a deep copy.